# Bounded subsets of $\Bbb C^2$.

Tags: complex-numbers, metric-spaces

Which of the following subsets of $\Bbb C^2$ are bounded?

1. $\{(z,w): z^2 + w^2 = 1\}$,
2. $\{(z,w): |Re z|^2 + |Re w|^2 = 1\}$,
3. $\{(z,w): |z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1\}$,
4. $\{(z,w): |z|^2 - |w|^2 = 1\}$.

For option $1$, I found some elements in the set but all have norm $1$. But still, I am not convinced.

option $3$ is the unit ball in $\Bbb R^4$ hence it is bounded. Other options I am not sure.

Please share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: The first set is unbounded : in particular, you cannot say the norm is 1 (don't forget that the nome is a $\ge 0$ number).

Comment: What has this problem to do with Riemann surfaces? Or with Complex Analysis, for that matter?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you. Can you please explain to me, why it is unbounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is unbounded, since it contains every pair of the form $(z,w)$, where $w$ is a square root of $1-z^2$.
2. It is unbounded, since it contains every pair $(1,it)$, with $t\in\Bbb R$.
3. You are right here.
4. It is unbounded, since it contains every par $(\cosh t,\sinh t)$, with $t\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you. Why $(z,\sqrt z)$ belongs to the set given in first option?

Comment: @JeanMarie Sure! I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. But is it immediate that set of all $(z,\sqrt{1-z^2})$ is unbounded? For example, in real case, such tuples are bounded. I am getting $d((0,0),(z,\sqrt{1-z^2}) = \sqrt{z^2 - \sqrt{1-z^2}}) = 1$.

Comment: I am getting $d((0,0),(z,\sqrt{1-z^2})) = \sqrt{z^2 - (\sqrt{1-z^2})^2} = 1$.

Comment: Which distance $d$ are you using in $\Bbb C^2$?

Comment: Usual metric. $d((z_1,w_1),(z_2,w_2)) = \sqrt{|z_2-z_1|^2+|w_2 - w_1|^2}$. I thought by default we need to assume the usual metric.

Comment: Then, if $z\in\Bbb C$ and if $w$ is a square root of $1-z^2$,$$d\bigl((0,0),(z,w)\bigr)=\sqrt{|z|^2+|w|^2}\geqslant\sqrt{|z|^2}=|z|.$$And $|z|$ can be arbirarily large.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand.